# Javascript not always running

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div set to display:none on pageload, and a button to open that div on click with this script.

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.buttonmain').click(function(){
            $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
          });
        });      

    </script>
```

It works sometimes, but not every time.
I tried to put the script on the top, on the main page etc. Its all the same.

Its build on Bootstrap.

Any ideas someone?

Go to my site [www.pb-studios.com](http://www.pb-studios.com), and click FIRMENKUNDE or PRIVATKUNDEN, doesnt matter. there is a button there under the intro text that says "Mehr über Uns". thats the button that is suppose to show/hide the div.

Comment: Maybe the element `.buttonmain` does not always have a `.toggle_container` as sibling?

Comment: Where is that code on your site? I'm not finding it anywhere, and it registers as an `eval` in firebug.

Comment: i get an error in Chrome that the following is not working `        $('#grid').grid(...` (nl: undefined is not a function). If i attach the exact same event from console it is working, so i would suggest you first try to debug the errors that might be blocking further attachments... In my case, the website 'more' button was never working

Comment: Thanx for answers, but i found a solution, just changed the script a little (removed (document).ready).
To me it now seems good, please tell me if it does not work for you:
`$( ".buttonmain" ).click(function() {
  $( ".toggle_container" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});`

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the `script` in the `body`, at the very bottom.

Comment: Did you base this off of his actual code? Did you modify where his script tag was and make it work by moving the script tag down? Also, jquery `ready` doesn't matter if it's at the top of the document or the bottom. It waits to fire. So this isn't it.